# Can`t I use jsf 2.0 el expression in f:attribute?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

When I use the following codes, I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error.

```
   <h:dataTable value="#{toDoBean.toDoItemList}" var="toDoItem" >

        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{toDoItem.finsh}"  
                                     valueChangeListener="#{toDoBean.onStatusChange}" 
                                     onchange="submit()"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{toDoItem.title}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="X" actionListener="#{toDoBean.onDelete}">
                <f:attribute name="id" value="#{toDoItem.title}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

But if I replaced

```
<f:attribute name="id" value="#{toDoItem.title}" />
```

with

```
<f:attribute name="id" value="testing" />
```

then everything work fine.

So my assumption is "I can`t use EL with f:attribute".

1. Am I right?
2. why?
3. Is there a way to use el in f:attribute?

Comment: “f:attribute” tag allow you to pass a attribute value to a component, or a parameter to a component via action listener.

Comment: Does `#{toDoItem.title}` resolve to a `String`? Does each row from your `<h:dataTable>` has `title` populated?

Comment: You should show your managedbean.

Comment: yes #{toDoItem.title} resolves to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Is your toDoItemList list have field title? if yes , does title have getter and setters?
And also please review

[jsf f:attribute](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_attribute_tag.htm)

Comment: of course, I have correct getter and setter in my ToDoItem class. you can assume my managed bean and other class is correct.